# QGIS Way to join based on different length keys fields?

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, string

In QGIS is there a way to join a .shp file to a table when the keys are different length (by ignoring part of one set of keys?)

For example .shp file key col like this
1500000US120730002001
1500000US120730002002
1500000US120730002003
(the 1500000US may be ignored because in this .shp file they are all the same)

Join File has a key col like this
120730002001
120730002002
120730002003

Comment: It would make the most sense to make a new field where you create a field calculation which parses from the left by X amount of digits. Left([fieldname], 9)

Comment: You can even use virtual field to join the tables. This way you needn't to add permanent redundant data to your table.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possibly. Take a look at the join dialog of the properties of the layer, you have not access to expressions from there. The best way to go would be Zoltans comment on using a virtual field.